# SSH Error - standard in must be a TTY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sudo, su

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
ssh -i FILENAME.pem ec2-user@ec2-00-000-00-00.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com su --session-command="./update.sh"
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
standard in must be a tty
```

How can I `SSH` on to the server then run the file called `./update.sh`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSH into your instance and run `sudo visudo`.  Find this line: `Defaults    requiretty` and add this line below it: `Defaults:ec2-user !requiretty` Save and exit.  *(If you're not familiar with `vi`, press `i` to go into insert mode to make changes to the file.  Then press `ESC` when done and `ZZ` to save and exit.)*

And then run the SSH command with the addition of the `-t` switch:

`ssh -t -i FILENAME.pem ec2-user@ec2-00-000-00-00.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com su --session-command="./update.sh"`